# Flask import is failing in standard environment of Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have specified an `app.yaml` file as follows:

```
runtime: python
env: standard
# this assumes that the entrypoint is app.py
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app
threadsafe: true
```

After running `gcloud app deploy` I'm faced with a 500 error and the logs reveal the following

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27_experiment/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27_experiment/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27_experiment/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/base/data/home/apps/g~test-website/20170924t080410.404328292497306090/app.py", line 3, in <module>
from flask import Flask, render_template
ImportError: No module named flask
```

Can anyone help me configure a standard environment

Comment: well, to fix the error message you need to upload the flask module as well as your app. This is a well known issue. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27

Comment: I did as follows, and with my configuration, it gives `No URLMap entries found in application configuration
  in "/home/dev_test/test-website/app.yaml", line 5, column 1`

Comment: ask a new question ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are combining syntax for the flexible environment and the standard environment in your `app.yaml`

Look at the [documentation for the `app.yaml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref) and stick to the standard environment reference. The `env` parameter is only used for `flex` and `entrypoint` is only for flex. The `runtime` parameter should be `python27` as `python` means the deprecated Python 2.5 runtime.

Given that you're trying to use Flask, you should probably read the [getting started guide that is specifically for Flask](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/python-standard-env).